# iOS: Scroll animations for all UIScrollview in the app stop working after a while

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm having a weird problem with UIScrollviews. I use them in various screens, menus, iCarousel, sometimes with paging and bounce.

After using the app for a while the scroll animations stop working. I can still scroll but after dragging ends there is no more "animation with velocity", scrolling just stops right away, even if I swipe "hard". All events still seem to fire. scrollRectToVisible works fine at the beginning but stops working completely after point of break. Even very simple scrollviews that have not been customized won't bounce back anymore.

I couldn't find a real cause/trigger so far, thus it's tough to post code since scrollviews are all over the place. I'm developing for iOS for more than 4 years now, using scrollviews extensively in most of my projects and I checked the obvious places in my code already. I hope someone else came across this and knows what's causing it.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I seem to have the exact same problem. A paging UIScrollView which works fine until something stops it. Then all momentum is lost when scrolling and the scroll view just tracks my finger, stopping motion the moment the finger is lifted. No momentum, paging or deceleration, nothing just an instant stop of the motion. scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating: gets invoked but scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: doesn't. If I mess with it for long enough then eventually the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: method does fire and everything goes back to normal.